# Pandas Dataframe to Postgres table conversion not working

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am converting a csv file into a Pandas dataframe and then converting it to Postgres table essentially.

The problem is that I am able to create a table in Postgres but I am unable to select column names from the table while querying it.

This is the sample code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pwd@localhost:5432/test')

def convertcsvtopostgres(csvfileloc, table_name, delimiter):
    data = pd.read_csv(csvfileloc, sep=delimiter, encoding='latin-1')

    data.head()
    data1 = data.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())

    data1.to_sql(table_name, engine, index=False)

convertcsvtopostgres("Product.csv","t_product","~")
```

I can do a `select * from test.t_product;` but I am unable to do a `select product_id from test.t_product;`

I am not sure if that is happening because of the encoding of the file and the conversion because of that. Is there any way around this, since I do not want to specify the table structure each time.

Comment: At a `psql` prompt, type `\d test.t_product`. That should show you the names of the columns in the `test.t_product` table. On the Python side, you could `print(data1.columns.tolist())` to see what Python thinks the column names are.

Comment: If that does not clarify what the issue is, please post a few lines of the csv file. That might help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have to use python/pandas? Otherwise, getting a CSV into a PostgreSQL table is supported out-of-the-box using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

Comment: No, its not necessary for me to use pandas/python. I just used it because I thought it would be better fit with the encoding piece of the problem that I have with the csv files.